# Adding user's photo to contest, call method with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I came from a JS background so Rails is weird to me. I currently have a show.html.erb for the contest model:

```
<h1>Contest name: <%= @contest.name %></h1>
<h2>Contest criteria: <%= @contest.criteria %></h2>

<h3>Photos: </h3>
<%= link_to "Enter Contest", "#" %>
<% @contest.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= image_tag("#{photo}") %>
<% end %>
```

With the `link_to` I'm trying to render all photos that belongs to the `current_user` and pick one of them to assign it to the current contest. The params passing seems all so mysterious to me. Can you guys point me in the right direction of how I should tackle this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand you need to select an image from list of images and pass the id. So, try this

```
<%= label_tag "Enter Contest" %>
<% @contest.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag("#{some photo path}")), some_controller_method_path(:photo_id => photo.id) %>
<% end %>
```

And in controller you can use `params[:photo_id]`

Comment: Thanks, I have it like this:

<%= label_tag "Enter Contest" %>
<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:thumb)), enter_contest_path(:photo_id) %>
<% end %>

but the error is "The action 'enter_contest' could not be found for StaticPagesController". Why would this call the action from the static_pages_controller instead of contest_controller?